# How to install RubyGems in Windows 10 in order to install Mongify

Tags: rubygems, mongify

What are the step by step instructions to install RubyGems on Windows 10?

I didn't find much content on the internet. Is it possible to install this using the command prompt?

The goal is to install Mongify, but RubyGems is a prerequisite for that.